# Open screen is not working with the line below

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile

I have one component, he open a modal...

App.js

```
import ScreenModal from './ScreenModal';

return (
    <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={ScreenModal}>
              <Text>Click</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
);
```

ScreenModal.js

```
function getModal() {
    return (
      <Modal isVisible={true}>
        <Text>Teste</Text>
      </Modal>
    )
}
```

He not open a modal (ScreenModal). where it is the error?

obs.: I have a custom modal

Answer (score 1):

your code should be like this

```js
//your modal component
const MyModalComponent = ({isVisible = true}) => {
    return (
      <Modal visible={isVisible}>
        <Text>Teste</Text>
      </Modal>
    )
}
```

and use it like that

```js
 
const App = () => {

   const [isVisible, setVisible] = React.useState(false);

   return(
     <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setVisible(true)}>
             <Text>Click</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    
        <MyModalComponent isVisible={isVisible} />
     </View>
   )

}
```

see docs example [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal)

Comment: Not function...

```
const App = () => {
   const [isVisible, setVisible] = React.useState(false);
   
  const MyModalComponent = ({isVisible = true}) => {
    return (
      <Modal visible={isVisible}>
        <Text>Teste</Text>
      </Modal>
    )
}

   return(
     <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setVisible(true)}>
             <Text>Click</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    
        <MyModalComponent isVisible={isVisible} />
     </View>
   )

}
```

Comment: It is arrow function expression is the same https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp